# Install clang failed, CMake Error

Tags: software-installation, compiling

When I install clang in my ubuntu 16.04, After I type command `make && make install` and waited for nearly 2 hours, it returns me the result that

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot make directory "/usr/local/include/llvm": Permission
  denied


Makefile:137: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

what should I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same directory, enter the following command:

```
sudo make install
```

The `sudo` gives `make` the root permissions it needs to finish installing clang, which has already successfully compiled.